# simple-linkedinphp: Undefined index: oauth

Tags: php, api, session, curl, linkedin-api

I'm using [simple-linkedinphp](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) and [OAuth library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) to connect to LinkedIn. When I run demo.3.0.2.php, connect with LinkedIn and press the blue button "Ok, I'll allow" I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: oauth on line 136.
LinkedIn->retrieveTokenAccess(): bad data passed, string type is required for $token, $secret and $verifier.
```

Examining the problem further it seems the session data is lost when LinkedIn returns to the script. cURL does seem to start a new session instead of using the initial session.

Comment: Can you test your PHP configuration to see if $_SESSION is working independantly of the demo script? http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-sessions.html?page=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in my config file caused the trouble:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".mywebsite.com");
```

Commenting this out solved the problem.

Comment: I take it you were running the demo script on a domain other than .mywebsite.com?

Comment: Indeed Paul, I was running the demo script on localhost.